# Monitoring cell voltage + charger voltage simultaneously?

Tags: circuit-design, battery-charging, measurement, voltage-measurement

I'm pretty sure this is a dumb question but, recently I was messing around trying to charge batteries with a DC power supply, and I wanted to log the progress.

It was a really naïve, dirt simple setup:

[image]

I wanted to track both the supply voltage the charger was putting across the battery, and also the actual voltage the cell was at. To do this, I'd log the voltage across the cell (charger voltage), then disconnect the charger and measure the voltage again.

My question is, is there some way to set it up so that I can monitor both at once, i.e. without having to disconnect the charger to measure the cell voltage?

Clarifications (maybe):

- "Supply" is a constant voltage supply (mostly; there's a max current above which the voltage will decrease). It's set at or slightly above the nominal cell voltage.
- "Supply Disconnect" isn't a real switch; it just represents the supply wire I have to disconnect temporarily to read the actual current cell voltage (which is a bit lower than the supply voltage when the cell has a low charge at the beginning).
- I'm taking two measurements: one with the "switch" closed, and one with the "switch" open. What I'm wondering is if there's a way to take both of those measurements (or something equivalent) without having to (dis)connect wiring or flip switches.

Comment: When you say "cell voltage" you mean the voltage of the cell with no current flowing -- yes?

Comment: @TimWescott Yeah; or as close to no current as possible given that measuring it takes some current (afaik), but basically, yeah. Basically "is the cell charged yet or not?" and also "what are the characteristics of this charger?" (for experimental logging).

Answer (score 1):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fuFcL4.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

If your PSU is floating, you connect the croc from scope on - terminal. You have to pay attention that circuit isn't grounded in any other point (if not floating) then connect scope probes.

Comment: I think what I was unclear about is, my goal is to eliminate that "switch". That "switch" isn't really a switch, it just represents me pulling a wire out of the charger so that I can measure cell voltage instead of charge-in-progress cell voltage. I think the complication here is I don't know what I'm doing and so I don't know how to describe my problem properly, I'm sorry.

Comment: So like, in your diagram, I'm not interested in VM2; I know what it is anyways because V1 is a constant voltage supply. What I'm interested in is VM1 with SW1 closed (charging) and SW2 open (actual cell voltage), and trying to get those two simultaneously without having to connect / disconnect wires. If that makes sense.